# Download manager for Firefox Quantum

Tags: web-browser, download-manager

I want a Firefox Quantum addon that will allow me to input urls and download them.

Similar to TabSave in chrome where you are able to paste a list of URLS and it downloads them automatically. 
Whether you paste the links in bulk yourself, or it accepts a text file as an input is irrelevant to me.

I found DownThemAll! addon, but unfortunately it is not supported in the newer versions of Firefox.

I found Turbo Download Manager but while it supports multiple downloads, you have to input them one by one manually. Which is useless when you ave potential hundreds of urls.

[image]